# How to setup codebuild with code pipelines in terraform?

Tags: terraform, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to setup codebuild to receive an artifact from code pipeline with terraform. The relevant part of the codebuild resource in the terraform file looks like this:

```
  source {
     type            = "CODEPIPELINE"
     git_clone_depth = 1
  }
```

I get an error when running `terraform apply` The error is:

> Error: Error creating CodeBuild project: InvalidInputException: Invalid input: when using CodePipeline both sourceType, and artifactType must be set to: CODEPIPELINE
>       status code: 400, request id: 2c32335e-d3c1-4abd-823b-83e26b947c77

There is nothing in the terraform docs about sourceType neither arifactType... How does one setup code build to receive an artifact from code pipeline with terraform? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This error is related to the build output artifact definition: [1]

To resolve, define **type = 'CODEPIPELINE'** for both 'source' and 'artifacts' properties on the TF resource: ***aws_codebuild_project***:

From https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codebuild_project.html#artifacts:

> source supports the following:
>
> type - (Required) The type of repository that contains the source code
>   to be built. Valid values for this parameter are: CODECOMMIT,
>   CODEPIPELINE, GITHUB, GITHUB_ENTERPRISE, BITBUCKET, S3 or NO_SOURCE.
>
> artifacts supports the following:
>
> type - (Required) The build output artifact's type. Valid values for
>   this parameter are: CODEPIPELINE, NO_ARTIFACTS or S3.

Share your TF template if you are still facing the issue.

Ref:

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_ProjectArtifacts.html

### Edit 1:

I copied your template and applied it and it ran without any issue. The only thing changed was bucket name and project name:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "shariqexampletestingterrastartup"  # <======

resource "aws_codebuild_project" "example" {
  name          = "terraform-cb-project" #var.DOMAIN_NAME # <======
```

Response of Terraform apply:

```
Plan: 5 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_iam_role.example: Creating...
aws_iam_policy.policy: Creating...
aws_s3_bucket.example: Creating...
aws_iam_role.example: Creation complete after 2s [id=example]
aws_iam_policy.policy: Creation complete after 3s [id=arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/test-policy]
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.test-attach: Creating...
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.test-attach: Creation complete after 2s [id=example-20200113052522878300000001]
aws_s3_bucket.example: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_s3_bucket.example: Creation complete after 15s [id=shariqexampletestingterrastartup]
aws_codebuild_project.example: Creating...
aws_codebuild_project.example: Creation complete after 3s [id=arn:aws:codebuild:us-east-1:123456789012:project/terraform-cb-project]
```

For reference, my TF version is as follows:

```
terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.10
+ provider.aws v2.44.0

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 0.12.19. You can update by downloading from www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

Comment: I have added the terraform template as you suggest, both of those items were filled out with the value CODEPIPELINE as you suggested

Comment: Please see Edit1.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I tested and worked for my usecase:

`codebuild.tf`:

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "code_build" {
  name                          = "${var.teamid}-${var.prjid}"
  description                   = "${var.teamid}-${var.prjid}"
  build_timeout                 = "5"
  service_role                  = var.codebuild_role
  artifacts {
    type                        = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }

  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_LARGE"
    image                       = "aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    privileged_mode             = true
  }

  source {
    type                          = "${var.build_source}"
    location                      = "${var.storage_bucket}"
    git_clone_depth               = var.git_clone_depth
    buildspec                     = "${file("${var.buildspec_filepath}")}"
  }

  tags = {
    Name                          = "${var.teamid}-${var.prjid}"
    Owner                         = "${var.email}"
    TeamId                        = "${var.teamid}"
    PrjId                         = "${var.prjid}"
  }
}
```

`input.tfvars`:

```
email                       = "demo@demo.com"
aws_region                  = "us-east-2"
codebuild_role              = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/service-role/codebuild-service-role"
storage_bucket              = "codepipeline-12345"
kms_keyid                   = "12345"
github_org                  = "tomarv2"
github_repo                 = "demo"
github_oauth_token          = "xyz"
build_source                = "CODEPIPELINE"
git_clone_depth             = "0"
buildspec_filepath          = "buildspec.yml"
teamid                      = "demo"
prjid                       = "demo-pipeline"
```